# List comprehension in Python under specific circumstances

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

```
lst_a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
lst_b = [[1, 4, 7], [6, 5, 4], [9, 8, 7]]
```

My goal is to check all nested lists in `lst_a` if the first entry == first entry of any element in `lst_b`. If it's not than copy ONLY THAT sublist. In this example he wouldn't copy `lst_a[0]` but 1 and 2.

I tried to achieve my goal with list comprehension but it won't work.

```
zero = [x[0] for x in lst_a]
if zero not in lst_b:
    # I don't know what to do here.
```

Creating a tuple or a dictionary isn't possible because the whole process is in a loop in which every second new data come in and I try to avoid copying duplicates to the list.

EDIT: `lst_b` should look like that after the whole process:

```
lst_b = [[1, 4, 7], [6, 5, 4], [9, 8, 7], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to provide an actual example of how your output should look?

Comment: Seems like you want to use the first element of any list as a key and you want to avoid duplicates, which makes me believe that a dictionary is indeed what you should use.

Comment: the list comprehension you are using creates a list `zero` which contains first element in each list in `x`.
The if condition that you are using doesn't execute inside the list comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be more efficient ways of doing this, but this accomplishes the goal.

```
>>> [a for a in lst_a if a[0] not in [b[0] for b in lst_b]]
[[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Extract all the first elements from `lst_b` into a set so you can check membership efficiently. Then use a list comprehension to copy all the sublists in `lst_a` that match your criteria.

```
first_elements = {x[0] for x in lst_b}
result = [x for x in lst_a if x[0] not in first_elements]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I prefer the other solution from ApplePie but your way is worth to keep in mind, too.

Comment: They're essentially the same except I use a set while he uses a list.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit of a mouthful, but not too bad:

```
lst_b.extend(x for x in lst_a if not any(x[0] == y[0] for y in lst_b)
```

If you want a *new* list rather than modifying `lst_b` in place, then

```
lst_c = lst_b + [x for x in lst_a if not any(x[0] == y[0] for y in lst_b)]
```

In either case, we examine each sublist `x` in `lst_a`. `any(x[0] == y[0] for y in lst_b)` is `True` if the first element of the sublist is equal to the first element of any sublist in `lst_b`. If that's *not* true, then we'll include `x` in our final result.

Using `any` allows us to avoid checking against *every* sublist in `lst_b` when finding a single match is sufficient. (There are cases where this could be more efficient than first creating an entire set of first elements, as in @barmar's answer, but on average that approach is probably more efficient.)

Comment: Interesting. Learned a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
exclude=set(next(zip(*lst_b))) 
lst_b+=[sl for sl in lst_a if sl[0] not in exclude]
>>> lst_b
[[1, 4, 7], [6, 5, 4], [9, 8, 7], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Explanation:

1. `zip(*lst_b)` is a generator of the inverse of the matrix `lst_b`, The `*` expands the sub lists and this creates a generator that yields `[(1, 6, 9), (4, 5, 8), (7, 4, 7)]` in turn.
2. `next(zip(*lst_b)` we only need the first element of that inverse: `(1,6,9)`
3. `set(next(zip(*lst_b)))` only need the uniq elements of that so turn into a set. You get `{1, 6, 9}` (order does not matter)
4. `[sl for sl in lst_a if sl[0] not in exclude]` filter on that condition.
5. `lst_b+=` extend `lst_b` with the filtered elements.

Profit!

Comment: What is the meaning of * in exclude?